# Workarounds for lack of HKT for the specific case F<Nothing> for an F<out X>

Tags: generics, kotlin, types, higher-kinded-types

Is there any way in Kotlin to separate `Foo` from `Bar` by leaving `defaultBar` abstract in the following minimal example?

```
sealed class Bar<out X> {
  data class Hello<X>(val who: X): Bar<X>()
  object Empty : Bar<Nothing>()
}

interface Foo {
  fun defaultBar(): Bar<Nothing> = Bar.Empty
  fun <P> foo(bar: Bar<P> = defaultBar()): Bar<P> = bar
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  println((object : Foo{}).foo(Bar.Hello("world")))
}
```

By "separate", I mean that I want `Foo` and `Bar` to be in two completely separate files, so they don't mention each other. The method `foo` is supposed to be "hard", and it should stay in `Foo`. The method `defaultBar` is supposed to be "trivial", it could be implemented anywhere. The only place where I want to mention both `Foo` and `Bar` should be some separate class that provides the concrete implementation of `defaultBar`.

---

#### What I've tried

The following attempt seemed promising for the first few moments:

```
sealed class Bar<out X> {
  data class Hello<X>(val who: X): Bar<X>()
  object Empty : Bar<Nothing>()
}

interface Foo<B>{
  fun <P: B> defaultB(): P
  fun <P: B> foo(bar: P = defaultB()): P = bar
}

object FooImpl : Foo<Bar<Any>> {
  override fun <P: Bar<Any>> defaultB(): P = Bar.Empty
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  println(FooImpl.foo(Bar.Hello("world")))
}
```

Unfortunately, Kotlin cannot derive from `Bar<out X>` and `P subtypeOf Bar<Any>` that `Bar<Nothing> subtypeOf P`.

Furthermore, I also can't write something like

```
sealed class Bar<out X> {
  data class Hello<X>(val who: X): Bar<X>()
  object Empty : Bar<Nothing>()
}

interface Foo<B, N: B> {
  fun defaultBar(): N
  fun <P : B super N> foo(bar: Bar<P> = defaultBar()): Bar<P> = bar
}

object FooImpl : Foo<Bar<Any>, Bar<Nothing>> {
  fun defaultBar(): Bar<Nothing> = Bar.Empty
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  println(FooImpl.foo(Bar.Hello("world")))
}
```

, because besides not supporting HKT's, Kotlin also doesn't support lower type bounds at use-site.

---

#### (optional) What I wished would be possible

The following Scala snippet shows what I mean:

```
sealed trait Bar[+X]
case class Hello(who: String) extends Bar[String]
case object Empty extends Bar[Nothing]

trait Foo {
  val defaultBar: Bar[Nothing] = Empty
  def foo[P](bar: Bar[P] = defaultBar): Bar[P] = bar
}

println((new Foo{}).foo(Hello("world")))
```

This can be refactored into:

```
import language.higherKinds

sealed trait Bar[+X]
case class Hello(who: String) extends Bar[String]
case object Empty extends Bar[Nothing]

trait Foo[B[+_]] {
  val defaultB: B[Nothing]
  def foo[P](b: B[P] = defaultB): B[P] = b
}

object FooImpl extends Foo[Bar] {
  val defaultB: Bar[Nothing] = Empty
}

println(FooImpl.foo(Hello("world")))
```

so that `Foo` does not mention `Bar` anywhere.

---

#### (optional) Why I hoped that it should be possible

Full HKT's aren't needed for this particular case, because we need to evaluate `Bar` only at a single type `Nothing`:

```
sealed trait Bar[+X]
case class Hello(who: String) extends Bar[String]
case object Empty extends Bar[Nothing]

trait Foo[N] {
  val defaultBar: N
  def foo[P >: N](bar: P = defaultBar): P = bar
}

object FooInstance extends Foo[Bar[Nothing]] {
  val defaultBar = Empty
}

println(FooInstance.foo(Hello("world")))
```

This works without higher kinds, Java's `super` would have been sufficient. But, as already mentioned above, Kotlin doesn't seem to have anything like `>:` / `super` / lower type bounds at use site.

---

#### Question

Is there anything that one could do except moving `foo` into `FooImpl`, i.e. merging `Foo` and `FooImpl` into one big file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can imitate `super` by making `foo` extension function and writing `B : P` instead of `P super B`:

```
sealed class Bar<out X> {
    data class Hello<out X>(val who: X) : Bar<X>()
    object Empty : Bar<Nothing>()
}

interface Foo<out B> {
    fun defaultBar(): B
}

fun <B : P, P> Foo<B>.foo(bar: P = defaultBar()): P = bar

object FooImpl : Foo<Bar<Nothing>> {
    override fun defaultBar(): Bar<Nothing> = Bar.Empty
}

fun main() {
    println(FooImpl.foo(Bar.Hello("world")))
}
```

Comment: This also works if `FooImpl` is actually some other interface and we want to expose `foo` to the implementing classes: for this, we just can move `fun <B> Foo<B>.foo(bar: B = defaultBar()): B = bar` into `Foo`. Thank you very much!